# Regular expression to allow only 5 digit number or alpha character followed by 5 digit number

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I want to create validation on a form field which checks that input is a valid ID.

Most of the IDs are simple 5 digit numbers, but there a few odd variations where the number could have a leading alpha character (an F or G so eg `F12345`) or ending in an alpha character (an A or B so eg `12345B`).

I have the regexp for a 5 digit number but I don't know where to go to allow F/G at the beginning or A/B at the end

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This regex should do:

```
/^([FG]?\d{5}|\d{5}[AB])$/
```

You can use `.test()` function of `RegExp` object to validate the string.

```
/^([FG]?\d{5}|\d{5}[AB])$/.test("F12345")
```

Comment: Awesome... that's exactly what I was after. I must get my head around regex at some point.